# My NSJSONSerialization seems like it's giving me nested NSDictionaries--how can I access specific keys within the outside key?

Tags: ios, json, swift, nsdictionary

I hope I phrased my question properly, I apologize if I didn't. Not entirely sure what's going on.

So I parsed the JSON with

```
let jsonData:NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &errors) as! NSDictionary
```

which produces:

```
{
"tests" =     (
            {
        age = 50;
        gender = m;
        vehicle = 1;
    },
            {
        age = 73;
        gender = m;
        vehicle = 14;
    },
            {
        age = 50;
        gender = m;
        vehicle = 22;
    },
            {
        age = 50;
        gender = m;
        vehicle = 23;
    },
```

.
.
.

When I print (jsonData["tests"] I get basically the same thing as an NSArray, except no "tests {...}" --it looks virtually the same other than that.

I want to populate a tableView with the "vehicle" entry from each element, so how can I get an array or something usable with just the "vehicle" entry from each. The only "key" I get when printing allKeys with the original NSDictionary is "tests" and I can't cast jsonData["tests"] as an NSDictionary to make new keys like "age, gender..."

tl;dr how can I go from the NSDictionary "jsonData" to an array of vehicle numbers which looks like, [1, 14, 22, 23].

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like your json is a Dictionary that contains an Array of Dictionaries so you should be able to cast what is coming out of `jsonData["tests"]` as an Array and then use .map() to create an array of just the vehicle numbers like this:

```
if let dictArray = jsonData["tests"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
  var vehicleArray = dictArray.map({ dict in
            dict["vehicle"]     
  })
  //Do something with vehicle array here
}
```

Comment: I had some issues with this. The dict in dict["vehicle"] part was throwing syntax errors. Even when fixed, however, it wasn't working the way I wanted it to work. I may have been overlooking something.

Comment: @ksm18 hmm odd, when i did it in a playground it printed out an array of vehicles, but i didn't create it from json, only as an Array of Dictionaries.  What issues were you seeing?

Comment: Got it to work: var vehicleArray = dictArray.map({dict in dict["vehicle"]}) --you were missing a parenthesis. I also misspoke earlier. I ended up using your response and not the other.

Answer (score 0):

You *have* done work so far by unwrapping a Dictionary with a single key/value pair into just the value.

But then, you don't actually need or want to create a separate array from what you now have. Just use proper mapping within your table dataSource functions. Keep it as an array of dictionary objects.

```
if let a = jsonData["tests"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
   myPersonArray = a
}
else { /* handle error */ }
// later

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  // get the cell, then:
  let vehicleNum = myPersonArray[indexPath.row]["vehicle"] as! Int
  cell.text = "\(vehicleNum)"
  // whatever else, then return the cell
}
```